# Will 'git gui' / 'git citool' able to trigger the git hooks pre-commit script?

Tags: git

I am able to launch the script by using 'git commit' normally. However when i try to use 'git gui' or 'git citool' the script is not launched at all. Would like to know if this 2 tools will invoke the script?

Edit:
OS is UNIX

Comment: They should be able to invoke the hooks. What's you `pre-commit` like? How do you find it does not work?

Comment: What's you pre-commit like?
--> I am using the pre-commit script to launch a python script, that does zipping for '.txt' into '.gz' to save disk space. Since this is a multiple user project, i dont want other committer to accidentally commit a '.txt' so i automate it with the pre-commit script. 

How do you find it does not work?
--> i code the script to 'print' whenever they finish a task. When i use 'git commit' the zipping is happening, however when i use 'git gui / git citool' i cant even see them in 'unstaged changes'

Comment: For `git gui`, when a hook is invoked, a message like `Calling pre-commit hook` is printed on the left-bottom corner of the window. If a hook encounters any error, a pop-up window shows up. And you need to press the button `Rescan` to refresh the window so that new untracked files show in the `Unstaged Changes` section.

Comment: a message like Calling pre-commit hook is printed on the left-bottom corner of the window. --> didnt see this when i did [git gui]. press the button Rescan to refresh the window so that new untracked files show in the Unstaged Changes section--> did this too but i still cant see the new untracked files. However my teammate did [git gui] and seems like the pre-commit script is working for him. I just cant figure out why it didnt work for my side.

Comment: My comment is based on `git gui` on Windows. Did `git gui` run in the same repository where you ran commands.

Comment: Yea, tried that too. still not appearing. i am trying to clone a fresh model and see if the same problem still happens or not

Comment: Tried everything, still not working

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the 'pre-commit' script is invoked without any message printed. My files are able to zipped automatically after i commit it even though i cant see 'them' being staged.